# How to pass an argument including a <SPACE> from C# to powershell.exe

Tags: c#, powershell, string-literals

I want to start a process in C# causing powershell to start another programm that requires a parameter like: "M=a b". I have tried various literal string formats, to no avail.
In PowerShell, the following works fine:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\MY.exe' -ArgumentList 'A','"M=a b"'
```

In C# is the following not working properly (My.exe throws : "M=a" ist not found.)

```
string arg = @"Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\MY.exe' -ArgumentList 'A','""M=a b""'";
psTry("powershell.exe",arg)

static void psTry(string file,string arg)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
    process.Start();
}
```

I tried various combinations of the 's and "s both in PowerShell and in C#. I tried things like

```
arg = @"...".ToString() + @"'""M=a b""'".ToString()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using _Process_ to call _PowerShell_ to then call your _.exe_? Why not just use _Process_ to call your _.exe_?

Comment: Because Process does not accept another item fom the -ArgumentList. And the question remains unsolved. @Joel Coehoorn thanks for editing.

Comment: If _Process_ didn't work without the use of _PowerShell_, then it's very likely that you didn't use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

- Replace `@"... '""M=a b""'"` with `@"... '\""M=a b\""'"`
- This turns into verbatim `'\"M=a b\"'` on the *process command line*, which makes PowerShell ultimately see `'"M=a b"'` as one of the `-ArgumentList` arguments in the `Start-Process` call (as in your successful in-session call), which - due to a long-standing bug that won't be fixed, see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) - is placed as verbatim `"M=a b"` on the process command line for `MY.exe`, which looks as follows in full:

  - `"C:\MY.exe" A "M=a b"`
  - Therefore, after parsing its command line, `MY.exe` will see two arguments, with verbatim values `A` and `M=a b`, respectively.

That is, inside your C# verbatim string , use `\""` to yield `\"`, which is needed in order to pass a `"` through *verbatim* to the PowerShell command that is ultimately executed.

[`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, requires `"` chars. to be retained as part of a command to be escaped as `\"`<sup>[1]</sup>
*Unescaped* `"` chars. are assumed to have syntactic function *on the command line only*, and are therefore *removed* before the (concatenation of the) argument(s) are evaluated as PowerShell code.

---

To spell it out the solution in full:

```cs
//  Note the `\` before `""`
string arg = @"-NoProfile Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\MY.exe' -ArgumentList 'A', '\""M=a b\""'";
psTry("powershell.exe", arg);

static void psTry(string file, string arg)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
    process.Start();
}
```

---

**Taking a step back**:

**If the sole intent is to launch another application with arguments, the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) needn't be involved at all** - you can **invoke `C:\MY.exe` *directly***, as shown below.

The only tricky aspect is that you must **set `process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`** in order to mimic `Start-Process`'s default behavior of **launching the application (process) in a *new window***:<sup>[2]</sup>

```cs
// Note how the arguments are passed *inside a single string*,
// with embedded double-quoting.
psTry("C:\MY.exe", @"A ""M=a b""");
void psTry(string file, string args)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // execute in NEW WINDOW
    process.Start();
}
```

If your C# application is using **.NET Core/ .NET 5+** rather than .NET Framework, **argument-passing can even be simplified / made conceptually clearer** via the **[`.ArgumentList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.ArgumentList) property**, which - as an alternative to the single-string [`.Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo.Arguments) property - accepts an ***array* of *literal* (unquoted) arguments**, with .NET taking care of any required quoting and/or escaping:

```cs
// .NET Core / .NET 5+ only:
// Pass the arguments as an *array* of *literal* tokens.
psTry("dep.exe", new [] { "A", "M=a b" });
void psTry(string file, string[] args)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = file;
    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        process.StartInfo.ArgumentList.Add(arg);
    }
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.Start();
}
```

---

<sup>[1] The same applies analogously to [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI; the latter alternatively accepts `""`; also, the latter requires placing `-Command` (`-c`) before the command arguments, which is *implied* in Windows PowerShell.</sup>

<sup>[2] In fact, that is precisely what PowerShell's `Start-Process` cmdlet does behind the scenes - it is simply a PowerShell-friendly wrapper around the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) and [`System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) .NET APIs.</sup>

Comment: @OlavZietlow, correct: it is what you need in a PowerShell CLI call to make PowerShell ultimately see `'"M=a b"'` as an `-ArgumentList` argument. I've also updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: If I use _Console.WriteLine(@" '\""M=a b\""'");_   I get _ '\"M=a b\"'_ . That's not a format, powershell works with. You will see, what I mean, if you try _ Start-Process -FilePath '"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"' -ArgumentList '\"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\hello world.txt\"'_.   And sure, _  Start-Process -FilePath '"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"' -ArgumentList '"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\hello world.txt"'_ works, but that is still not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: @OlavZietlow, re formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting; you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``

Comment: @OlavZietlow, run the following from `cmd.exe` (Command prompt) to see that the proposed escaping works: `powershell -c Write-Output '\"M=a b\"'`

Comment: () The escape sequence works, true, but that was done by the "@" anyway- and I tried it beforehand in MessageBox.Show(). I received the correct string (i.e. '"M=a b"'), but MY.exe throws again the "M=a" ist not found. I tried the sequence without using the "@" and escaping every <"> with the \. Didn't help.

Comment: @OlavZietlow, please use the formatting instructions from my earlier comment - otherwise what you're trying to show is very hard to read.

Comment: @OlavZietlow, you may be missing that the ``\`` chars. _remain_ in the string that the verbatim string produces - which is crucial for the PowerShell call to work as intended. The instructions in this answer should result in the same call that you show as effective when called from inside PowerShell: `Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\MY.exe' -ArgumentList 'A','"M=a b"'`, and that's what I see in my tests. That is, `MY.exe`, after parsing its process command line, will see two verbatim arguments: `A` and `M=a b`

Comment: @OlavZietlow, if you want to get to the bottom of this, you'll need to provide more specific, properly formatted feedback. Please also see my update, which shows you how to call your application _without PowerShell_.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the **cmd.exe** showed, where my code broke. I had to add one *`\`* each for the *powershell.exe* and the *MY.exe*, where the **@** made the error less evident. Thanks to the patient helper.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like an answer to add---more like a comment to make under the site "patient helper"?